# How to use Typescript generics to parameterize parsing grammars?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I would like to write in (current) Typescript a general parser parameterized over symbols particular to language grammars.

Below is the simplest of several tried approaches of parameterizing `Sym`, the type for the symbols that varies per language grammar, but the first line in **Parser.js** fails type checking:

> Type `Sym` does not satisfy the constraint `string | number | symbol`.

Every way I tried to adjust the definition of `GrammarRules<Sym>` that resolved the issue unfortunately resulted in further downstream problems, only some of portion of which were themselves resolvable – couldn't find a full solution.

How can I define the symbol type, `Sym`, differently for each parser language and handle generically in **Parser.js**?   I'm open to substantially re-working some or all of the declarations and code to get the cleanest overall solution.

### Parser.ts

```
export type GrammarRules<Sym> = Record<Sym, GrammarRule<Sym>>
export type GrammarRule<Sym> = { lhs: Sym /* further uses of Sym type */ }

export class Parser<Sym> {
  rules: GrammarRules<Sym>
  private str: string
  /* Various other datastructure declarations with types dependent on Sym */

  constructor(rules: GrammarRules<Sym>) {
    this.rules = rules
  }
  parse(startSym: Sym, str: string) {
    this.str = str
    console.log(this.rules[startSym].lhs)
    // ...
  }
}
```

### ParserLangABC.ts

```
import { Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"

type Sym = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
const rulesABC: GrammarRules<Sym> = {
  A: { lhs: 'A' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ },
  B: { lhs: 'B' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ },
  C: { lhs: 'C' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ }
}
class ParserLangABC<Sym> extends Parser<Sym> {
  static parse(str: string) {
    const parser = new Parser(rulesABC)
    parser.parse('A', str)
  }
  // Other supporting methods parameterized to Sym
}
```

### ParserLangDEF.ts

```
import { Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"

type Sym = 'D' | 'E' | 'F'
const rulesDEF: GrammarRules<Sym> = {
  D: { lhs: 'D' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ },
  E: { lhs: 'E' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ },
  F: { lhs: 'F' /* rhs with further data of type Sym */ }
}
class ParserLangDEF<Sym> extends Parser<Sym> {
  static parse(str: string) {
    const parser = new Parser(rulesDEF)
    parser.parse('D', str)
  }
  // Other supporting methods parameterized to Sym
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with parsers but I think this is what you want regarding templates. The key is to define `export type SymBase = string | number | symbol;` and replace `Sym` with `Sym extends SymBase` where needed.

```
diff b/Parser.ts a/Parser.ts
1c1
< export type GrammarRules<Sym> = Record<Sym, GrammarRule<Sym>>
---
> export type SymBase = string | number | symbol;
> export type GrammarRules<Sym extends SymBase> = Record<Sym, GrammarRule<Sym>>
4c4
< export class Parser<Sym> {
---
> export class Parser<Sym extends SymBase> {
diff b/ParserLangABC.ts a/ParserLangABC.ts
1c1
< import { Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"
---
> import { SymBase, Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"
9c9
< class ParserLangABC<Sym> extends Parser<Sym> {
---
> class ParserLangABC<Sym extends SymBase> extends Parser<Sym> {
diff b/ParserLangDEF.ts a/ParserLangDEF.ts
1c1
< import { Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"
---
> import { SymBase, Parser, GrammarRules } from "./Parser"
9c9
< class ParserLangABC<Sym> extends Parser<Sym> {
---
> class ParserLangABC<Sym extends SymBase> extends Parser<Sym> {
```

Comment: Defining a base type that's separately extended works and was a good idea.  Thanks!